# Connect two nodes with an edge JavaFX

Tags: javafx, drawing, line, coordinates, nodes

I'm trying to write the correct rule about `connecting nodes with edge`. I've used solution from stackoverflow that use the data from two connectable `nodes`:

```
        line.startXProperty().bind( source.layoutXProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
        line.startYProperty().bind( source.layoutYProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));

        line.endXProperty().bind( target.layoutXProperty().add( target.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0));
        line.endYProperty().bind( target.layoutYProperty().add( target.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
```

But it didn't work well. It draws next line:
[image]

So I can not understand how should I write the rule so that line would be placed on it's place? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "add(x.getBoundsInParent()" part? It seems that the layout properties return the center of the circle so that could be enough

Comment: thanks, it is working. But on moving nodes, lines do not move after them. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I assume you're aware that, source.layoutXProperty().add(source.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() is `double`, and it is not `Observable`.
So if those are circles then you should calculate linestartpoint end lineendpoint from centerxpropery and radiusprop(assuming you want the edge of the circle), otherwise you could use some other `Observable` value of your nodes, or probably invalidation/change listener to get the desired effect(in case your nodes are moving)

Comment: Or you could just create a doublebinding, depend on layoutXprop and in the overriden compute() calc with getBoundsInParent().getWidth()

Some code that may be irrelevant for you:
[link](https://github.com/csumpakabra/ConnectEdge/blob/master/src/connectedge/ConnectEdge.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
line.startXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    Bounds b = source.getBoundsInParent();
    return b.getMinX() + b.getWidth() / 2 ;
}, source.boundsInParentProperty());
line.startYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    Bounds b = source.getBoundsInParent() ;
    return b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2 ;
}, source.boundsInParentProperty());
```

and similarly for the target and end of the line. The comments below the question basically explain how this works: you need something that is observable that depends on the bounds in parent and computes the center.

SSCCE (click to add a circle, click again to add a connected circle, drag circles to see effect):

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggingConnectedNodes extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        ObjectProperty<Node> lastUnconnectedNode = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            Circle c = createDraggingCircle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 25, pane, randomColor());
            pane.getChildren().add(c);
            if (lastUnconnectedNode.get() == null) {
                lastUnconnectedNode.set(c);
            } else {
                connect(lastUnconnectedNode.get(), c);
                lastUnconnectedNode.set(null);
            }

        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void connect(Node n1, Node n2) {
        if (n1.getParent() != n2.getParent()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nodes are in different containers");
        }
        Pane parent = (Pane) n1.getParent();
        Line line = new Line();
        line.startXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            Bounds b = n1.getBoundsInParent();
            return b.getMinX() + b.getWidth() / 2 ;
        }, n1.boundsInParentProperty()));
        line.startYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            Bounds b = n1.getBoundsInParent();
            return b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2 ;
        }, n1.boundsInParentProperty()));
        line.endXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            Bounds b = n2.getBoundsInParent();
            return b.getMinX() + b.getWidth() / 2 ;
        }, n2.boundsInParentProperty()));
        line.endYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            Bounds b = n2.getBoundsInParent();
            return b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2 ;
        }, n2.boundsInParentProperty()));
        parent.getChildren().add(line);
    }

    private Circle createDraggingCircle(double radius, double x, double y, Pane parent, Color fill) {
        Circle c = new Circle(radius, x, y, fill);
        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLoc = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        c.setOnMousePressed(e -> mouseLoc.set(new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY())));
        c.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double deltaX = e.getX() - mouseLoc.get().getX();
            double deltaY = e.getY() - mouseLoc.get().getY();
            c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + deltaX);
            c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() + deltaY);
            mouseLoc.set(new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        });
        c.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, Event::consume);
        return c ;
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return new Color(rng.nextDouble(), rng.nextDouble(), rng.nextDouble(), 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, James, I'll try. I still wonder why do you still waste your time on my stupidity :D
I still don't understand a little thing. Isn't it right that the Edge has to be Observer and Node be Observable? We move node, so the Edge is the one who need to observe node's actions, isn't it?

Comment: The edge is observing the node, or at least the properties of the edge are observing properties of the node. `startX` is a property of the edge, and it observes the `boundsInParent` property of the node. (And anything in JavaFX that is represented by a JavaFX property - which is almost everything - is observable.)

Comment: Your advice really did help. But edges are still overlapping nodes and for some reason `toFront` and `toBack` methods doesn't work.